# Code to see if user input was filled

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a field was filled in. I have an imcompleted code:

```
print "What is your name?"
user_input = gets.chomp.upcase

if user_input = ??
  print "Nice to meet you user_input!"
else 
  puts "Please enter your name."
end
```

How do I complete the code to do that?

Comment: "How do I do that?" – You do it by defining what "filled in" means, then write a program which checks whether `user_input` conforms to that definition. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so]. Also, since you tagged this question with [tag:performance], you should

Comment: … define, what *precisely* you mean by "performance": are you talking about throughput? About latency? About jitter? Are you talking about cold-start, warm-start or steady-state performance? What are your typical loads that you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of context missing from the question, but there are a couple of things that may be helpful to you.

1. Basic check if it's nil or empty:

   ```
   if user_input.nil? || user_input.empty?
       # Ask the user to try again
   end
   ```
2. Check if it matches a pattern you specify using a Regex (see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html). For example:

   ```
   if user_input =~ /^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+/
       # One uppercase character, followed by at least one lowercase
   end
   ```

The second option has far more possibilities, but again it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Under the premise that you would like to:

- **Print out a message**: "What is your name?"
- **Have the user enter their name and store it in the `user_input` variable**(with `gets.chomp`)
- **Output either "Nice to meet you << user name >>" or "Please enter your name"** depending on whether the input matches certain criteria

...we have a few changes to make.

The first being the condition of checking to *make sure the input isn't blank* and the second being *seeing if the input matches a certain value*.

First, let's check to see if the input is empty before continuing. We can use [String#empty](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-empty-3F) to make sure the string has at least one character (including whitespace):

```
print "What is your name?"
user_input = gets.chomp.upcase

# Check to make sure the input isn't empty
if !user_input.empty?
  print "Nice to meet you user_input!"
else 
  puts "Please enter your name."
end
```

Then, we can check to see if the input matches certain criteria. Unfortunately, your question doesn't specify what these criteria are, so as other users are suggesting you can use regex to see if it matches a particular pattern, or just use a hard coded string to compare:

```
print "What is your name?"
user_input = gets.chomp.upcase

# After making sure the input is empty, check to make sure it matches the string "Bob"
if !user_input.empty? && user.input == "Bob"
  print "Nice to meet you user_input!"
else 
  puts "Please enter your name."
end
```

Lastly, there is one bug in the code. The output once a user's input has been validated will always be "Nice to meet you user_input", even when the `user_input` variable is another value. This is because we aren't using [String Interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html) properly:

```
print "What is your name?"
user_input = gets.chomp.upcase

if !user_input.empty? && user.input == "Bob"
  # When using string interpolation, surround the variable you'd like to print with #{}
  print "Nice to meet you #{user_input}!"
else 
  puts "Please enter your name."
end
```

As other users have stated, you should consider fine tuning the requirements of your problem a bit more. You can add a lot of detail and experimentation to this simple example!

Answer (score -1):

```
if user_input.blank?
puts "please enter your name"
else
puts "Nice to met you"
end
```